# How to Create Dynamic Breadcrumbs Component?

Tags: javascript, next.js, strapi

How to write down the product category breadcrumbs on the product page?  Breadcrumbs on the product detail page as the parent category of the product.

I use Next.js and Strapi.

Like this:
[image: An example what I want]

This is the code for my product details page.

`product/[slug].js:`

```js
    import { useRef, useState } from "react";
    import { useEffect } from "react";
    import { toast } from "react-toastify";
    import { AiOutlineClose } from "react-icons/ai";
    import { MdMarkEmailUnread } from "react-icons/md";
    import { RiWhatsappFill } from "react-icons/ri";
    import { useRouter } from "next/router";
    import Link from "next/link";
    
    import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser";
    import ProductDetailsCarousel from "@/components/ProductDetailsCarousel";
    import Wrapper from "@/components/wrapper";
    import { fetchDataFromApi } from "@/utils/api";
    
    import Breadcrumbs from "@/components/breadcrumbs";
    
    const ProductDetails = ({ category, product, slug }) => {
        useEffect(() => {
            // Show the breadcrumb as a toast message
            const categoryName = category?.data?.[0]?.attributes?.name;
    
            if (categoryName) {
                toast.toast;
    
                success(`You are viewing: ${categoryName}`, {
                    position: "bottom-center", // You can adjust the position of the toast
                });
            }
        }, [category]);
        const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
        const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
        const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);
        const router = useRouter();
        const formRef = useRef();
        const handleCloseForm = () => setShowForm(false);
        const handleEmail = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
    
            // service id, template id, public key
            emailjs
                .sendForm(
                    "service_r1y667c",
                    "template_xawu22j",
                    formRef.current,
                    "IchOEgLgYWg5ok6ar"
                )
                .then(
                    () => {
                        toast.success(
                            "Email has been sent succcessfully to your email " + email
                        );
                        handleCloseForm();
                    },
                    (err) => {
                        toast.error(err.text);
                    }
                );
        };
        const p = product?.data?.[0]?.attributes;
    
        return (
            <div className="w-full md:py-12 relative">
                <Wrapper>
                    <div className="flex flex-col lg:flex-row md:px-10 md:gap-[50px] lg:gap-[20px] md:mt-10">
                        {/* left colum start */}
                        <div className="w-full md:w-auto flex-[1.5] max-[350px] lg:max-w-full mx-auto lg:mx-0">
                            <ProductDetailsCarousel images={p.image.data} />
                        </div>
    
                        {/* left colum end */}
    
                        {/* right colum start*/}
                        <div className="flex-[1] py-3">
                            <div></div>
                            {/* product title */}
                            <div className="text-sm md:text-xl lg:text-2xl font-semibold mb-2">
                                {p.name}
                            </div>
    
                            {/* product subtitle */}
                            <div className="text-xs md:text-md text-gray-400  mb-5">
                                {p.subtitle}
                            </div>
                            {/* product desc */}
                            {/* product Weight(Grams) */}
                            <div className="py-4">
                                <div className="text-xs md:text-md  mb-2">
                                    <span className="font-bold">Weight(GRAMS):</span> {p.weight}
                                </div>
                                {/* product height */}
                                <div className="text-xs md:text-md   mb-2">
                                    <span className="font-bold">Composition:</span> {p.composition}
                                </div>
                                <div className="text-xs md:text-md   mb-2">
                                    <span className="font-bold">Goods number:</span> {p.procode}
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                            <hr />
                            {/* product desc */}
                            <div className="text-xs md:text-md mt-2 mb-5 py-3">
                                {p.description}
                            </div>
    
                            {/*Email whatsapp contact start */}
                            <div className="flex justify-center items-center gap-20">
                                <button
                                    className="py-4 bg-amber-500 p-4 text-white shadow-md rounded-md flex justify-center items-center gap-2"
                                    onClick={() => setShowForm(true)}
                                >
                                    <p>
                                        <MdMarkEmailUnread className="w-6 h-6" />
                                    </p>
                                    <p>Email Now</p>
                                </button>
                                <Link
                                    href={"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=18758887700"}
                                    target={"_blank"}
                                    className="py-4 bg-green-500 p-4 text-white shadow-md rounded-md flex justify-center items-center gap-2"
                                >
                                    <p>
                                        <RiWhatsappFill className="w-6 h-6" />
                                    </p>
                                    <p>Whatsapp</p>
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                            {/*Email whatsapp contact end*/}
                        </div>
                        {/* right colum end*/}
                    </div>
                    {/* <RelatedProducts /> */}
                    {showForm && (
                        <div
                            className="absolute m-auto top-0 inset-x-0 left-0 bottom-9 w-full md:w-[480px] h-full flex justify-center items-center z-10"
                            onClick={handleCloseForm}
                        >
                            <div
                                className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center bg-white shadow-md rounded-md relative w-full h-[680px]"
                                onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
                            >
                                <h2 className="text-2xl py-4">Email me</h2>
                                <form
                                    className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full  gap-12 p-2"
                                    onSubmit={handleEmail}
                                    ref={formRef}
                                >
                                    <input
                                        className="w-full py-4 border border-gray-500 p-2"
                                        type="email"
                                        placeholder="Your Email"
                                        name="from_name"
                                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                                    />
                                    <textarea
                                        className="w-full py-4 border border-gray-500 p-2"
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder="Message..."
                                        name="message"
                                        onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
                                    />
                                    <button
                                        onClick={() => setShowForm(true)}
                                        className="w-full py-2 bg-lime-400 text-white"
                                    >
                                        Send
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                                <AiOutlineClose
                                    onClick={handleCloseForm}
                                    className="absolute top-8 right-8 w-6 h-6 text-red-600"
                                />
                                <div className=""></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </Wrapper>
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    export default ProductDetails;
    
    export async function getStaticPaths() {
        const products = await fetchDataFromApi("/api/products?populate=*");
        const category = await fetchDataFromApi("/api/categories?populate=*");
    
        const productPaths = products?.data?.map((p) => ({
            params: {
                slug: p.attributes.slug,
            },
        }));
    
        const categoryPaths = category.data.map((c) => ({
            params: {
                slug: c.attributes.slug,
            },
        }));
    
        const paths = [...productPaths, ...categoryPaths];
    
        return {
            paths,
            fallback: false,
        };
    }
    
    export async function getStaticProps({ params: { slug } }) {
        const category = await fetchDataFromApi(
            `/api/categories?filters[slug][$eq]=${slug}`
        );
        const product = await fetchDataFromApi(
            `/api/products?populate=*&filters[slug][$eq]=${slug}`
        );
        const products = await fetchDataFromApi(
            `/api/products?populate=*&[filters][slug][$ne]=${slug}`
        );
    
        return {
            props: {
                category,
                product,
                products,
                slug,
            },
        };
    }
```

This is the product details page, and I hope to have a breadcrumb component that can display the navigation style of the category in the upper part.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make make a map/matrix with all urls that you have, in your case it will have, lets say 3 layers/3 deeps.
Let say you have deep 1 layer: home etc., deep 2 layers: all category etc., deep 3 layer: solid. So in this way you can create `breadcrumbs` logic.

Ideally it's better to have some `Taxonomy` model, but `Strapi` doesn't have it yet, but here is proposal in their [roadmap](https://strapi.canny.io/customization/p/parent-child-relationshipfield).

Anyway imho there is no easy/fast solution for creating `breadcrumbs`. I need it as well, so my solution is that I was described above.